# An error occurred in the requested FTP operation. Detailed error description: 200 Type set to A 227 Entering Passive Mode (10,102,1,229,224,170)

Tags: ssis, ftp

I am attempting to connect to an FTP server within SSIS to download files, and receive the following error message

```
Error: 2018-02-01 10:05:47.57
   Code: 0xC002F304
   Source: Get all files from FTP FTP Task
   Description: An error occurred with the following error message: "An error occurred in the requested FTP operation. Detailed error description: 200 Type set to A
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,102,1,229,224,170)

".
End Error
```

Has anyone encountered this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: How do you connect to FTP? + Is `10.102.1.229` an IP address of your FTP server? + Can you download files from that FTP server using any standalone FTP client running on the **same machine** as SSIS?

Comment: This is commonly an issue with the FTP server and firewall settings. Are you trying to connect to an FTP server on an internal network, or external? Can you connect to it with Windows Explorer, or another FTP client?

Comment: i was able to download from a unix command line, however not from filezilla and not from SSIS. partner later informed me they replaced their servers. and had to configure new server to match old server. Issue was they needed to enable PASSIVE mode on the server.

Answer (score 2):

> 227 Entering Passive Mode (10,102,1,229,224,170)

The server returns an IP address like 10.x.x.x. This is an IP address in the private address space, which means that it is not routable over the internet. I assume that your client is not in the same network as the server and thus can not connect to this private IP address over the internet. Your client detects this problem and croaks.

The real fix need to be done at the server side. Some clients can be configured to attempt to work around such broken servers, ignore the shown IP address and instead try to connect to the same IP as on the FTP control connection but using the port given in the PASV response. This helps on some cases of broken server configuration but not in all cases.

If you have the choice to use a different protocol like SFTP/SCP (but not FTPS) or HTTP to connect to the server I recommend to use these. FTP is known to cause lots of trouble if firewalls or NAT is involved - which means trouble in large parts of the internet.

Comment: thanks the number after seems to be a list of flags and not an actual IP Address. we got it fixed. thanks, it was that the server needed to have passive mode enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The FTP Server needs to have PASSIVE mode turned on.
This resolved the issue.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "passive mode turned on" but the server obviously has sent a reply to a PASV command - only the wrong one.  That's why I rather assume that passive mode was not off but instead configured wrong. Your answer would actually be more helpful for other running into the same problem if you describe what kind of server this was and what setting you've exactly changed and to which value.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich a vendor fixed or i would be more elaborate. i had to depend on someone elses translation of what their IT department did to fix it. Appreciate the feed back

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use vsftpd, set

```
    pasv_min_port=21000
    pasv_max_port=21999
```

in vsftpd.conf file.

2. Open that port range in your network console panel of your VPS/Cloud provider.

This solve my same error.